# How to disable phase/objection trace messages in UVM?

Tags: uvm

I'm seeing all the phase/objection/configDB/resourceDB trace related messages in my simulation log. I am not passing any command line arguments to enable these, but still they are displayed.

I was able to disable configDB and resourceDB messages using the below statements.
uvm_resource_db_options::turn_off_tracing();
uvm_config_db_options::turn_off_tracing();
But, I couldn't find any options for phase and objection tracing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the simulation tool was adding the following defines whenever debug option was enabled.

```
+UVM_CONFIG_DB_TRACE
+UVM_PHASE_TRACE
+UVM_RESOURCE_DB_TRACE
+UVM_OBJECTION_TRACE
+UVM_FACTORY_TRACE
```

After I removed that debug option, the trace messages are gone.